# How do I make AntiForgeryToken work with Orchard CMS?

Tags: orchardcms, csrf

Using Orchard CMS 1.4.2, I'm having trouble posting a form in my custom module.

Here's my view:

```
@model ProfileEntity

<h2>My Profile</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FirstName)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MiddleNames)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.MiddleNames)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Surname)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Surname)

    <input type="submit" value="Save Profile"/> 
}
```

In my Module.txt file, I have the line:

```
AntiForgery: enabled
```

When I try posting this form, I get an exception:

```
[HttpAntiForgeryException (0x80004005): A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid.]
   System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgeryWorker.Validate(HttpContextBase context, String salt) +121176
   System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.Validate(HttpContextBase httpContext, String salt) +45
   System.Web.Mvc.ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) +68
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +343
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +116
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   Orchard.Mvc.Routes.HttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) in D:\Visual Studio Projects\ESW_EAPExchange\Orchard\src\Orchard\Mvc\Routes\ShellRoute.cs:147
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8970061
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```

I have also tried using:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryTokenOrchard()
```

instead of

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

(I'm not sure of the difference)

but it gives the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at one of dozens of example throughout the code of existing modules.

```
@using (Html.BeginFormAntiForgeryPost())
```